# How can I remove a line with Ant replaceregexp, but not leave an empty line

Tags: ant

I have the following text file:

```
    Manifest-Version: 3.0.0
    Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
    Created-By: 10.0-b19 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
    Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover;bundle-version="1.
     1.0"
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.qnx.doc.gestures.lib_ref
    Bundle-Version: 3.0.0.20121120
    Bundle-Localization: plugin
    Bundle-Name: %plugin.name
    Bundle-Vendor: %plugin.providername
```

And I'm trying to use the following pattern in a replaceregexp task

```
    regexp pattern='Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover;bundle-version="1.
   [\s\S]*'
```

To end up with this:

```
    Manifest-Version: 3.0.0
    Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
    Created-By: 10.0-b19 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
     1.0"
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.qnx.doc.gestures.lib_ref
    Bundle-Version: 3.0.0.20121120
    Bundle-Localization: plugin
    Bundle-Name: %plugin.name
    Bundle-Vendor: %plugin.providername
```

The trouble is I keep getting this:

```
    Manifest-Version: 3.0.0
    Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
    Created-By: 10.0-b19 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

     1.0"
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.qnx.doc.gestures.lib_ref
    Bundle-Version: 3.0.0.20121120
    Bundle-Localization: plugin
    Bundle-Name: %plugin.name
    Bundle-Vendor: %plugin.providername
```

What should my regex be to get rid of the empty line?

Thanks.

Comment: This will leave you with an invalid manifest - the `1.0"` is a continuation of the previous line, there because the manifest specification requires long lines to be wrapped. Ideally you should use a proper manifest file parser, but unfortunately the Ant `manifest` task doesn't seem to support _removing_ attributes, only adding or modifying them.

Comment: Thanks.  I realize the manifest will be invalid and I plan to remove the 1.0" as well once I find out how to get rid of the empty lines :-)  I just dont need the dependency on that bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Require-Bundle: org\.eclipse\.linuxtools\.cdt\.libhover;bundle-version="1\.\s*1.0"\s*
```

(using `\s*` to match zero or more whitespace characters, which include `\r` and `\n`) but since you're dealing with a manifest file it would make more sense to use a proper manifest parser.  Unfortunately the Ant `<manifest>` task doesn't provide a way to remove attributes, but it's pretty straightforward with a `<script>` task:

```
<property name="manifest.file" location="path/to/manifest.txt" />

<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    importPackage(java.io);
    importPackage(java.util.jar);

    // read the manifest
    manifestFile = new File(project.getProperty('manifest.file'));
    manifest = new Manifest();
    is = new FileInputStream(manifestFile);
    manifest.read(is);
    is.close();

    // remove the offending attribute
    manifest.getMainAttributes().remove(new Attributes.Name('Require-Bundle'));

    // write back to the original file
    os = new FileOutputStream(manifestFile);
    manifest.write(os);
    os.close();
]]></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ian, for your quick response and correction of my technique.  You solved my problem and I've learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

```
<replaceregexp file="manifest.mf" match='Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover;bundle-version=\"[^\"]+\"[\r\n]*' replace="" flags="m"/>
```

This works for me.